# Are the victims of Wrathful Aspect spared if they are immune to Fear?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers

As *Wrathful Aspect*, a level 2 Hexblade Utility, is currently worded, it has the Fear keyword (along with Fire and Arcane). If a creature who were immune to Fear were to attack the Hexblade that has activated *Wrathful Aspect* with a melee attack, would they also be immune to the damage from the power due to their immunity to the Fear keyword?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the immunity does not include damage.

> *Rules Compendium, page 225*
>
> If a creature is immune to charm, fear, illusion, or poison, it is unaffected by the non-damaging effects of a power that has that keyword.

Comment: nice catch. So in this case the fire damage definitely applies.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for!